# No emulators are currently running

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-emulator, virtual-device-manager

[No emulators are currently running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmtZ5.jpg)

Wrote a program in Kotlin. Everything was fine, everything worked. I turned on my laptop a week later. Launched Android Studio/AS/. The code opens fine. Only emulators do not display the phone. Writes that there are no working emulators. No reboots of either the system or the AS, updates with a full restart of the program help. I want to delete the device, Device Manager/DM/ also does not allow it, because DM says that it is now working. I can’t find any AVD services. In the Task Manager, I can’t find anything either.
Dear gurus advise what to do.
The next step is to reinstall AS. I just can’t reinstall AS every time the emulator freezes.
Thanks in advance.

By the way, as I have no choice I reinstall the AS that helps.

Comment: Did u try File -> Invalid Caches -> Invalidate and restart

Comment: Probably a config file value is still set to running. Find the emulator's folder by visiting `Android Studio > Tools > Device Manager > Device you want to delete > Show on Disk`. Go to parent folder and delete the problematic emulator.